# Minecraft - how do I add a PNG for a new Mob to either assets or resourcepacks

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I've installed MCP and set up eclipse and successfully added my new monster to the game. It spawns properly and does everything I meant it to do. The only problem I still have is that the texture that I've indicated cannot be found. The game logs contains the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: minecraft:textures/entity/spider/green_spider.png
       at net.minecraft.client.resources.FallbackResourceManager.getResource(FallbackResourceManager.java:51) ~[minecraft/:?]
```

I browsed various wikis and tuorials, some of which suggested that I need to add an asset folder to src/minecraft, but that didn't work. I found out that I could add my texture file to `[mcp]/jars/resourcepacks/` but that didn't work either.

Can you tell me to configure resource pack loading or what to run in MCP to add my asset files to the game?

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack might help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack, you should create a resource pack by copying the asset folder into a new directory, adding your files to the asset dir and creating an pack.mcmeta file, which you place next to the asset folder. Zip the whole lot and place it in your .minecraft/resourcepack dir. In the game, go to options, resource packs and add your resource pack to the selected pack list.